# How to change the color of bar in shap.plot.bar and shap.plots.waterfalls?

Tags: python-3.x, shap

As mentioned in the question, is there anyway we can change color of bar and waterfall plot in shap plot? I didn't see any option to change it. I tried using matplotlib to change the color but that didn't solve the issue. I can add the title but can't change the color. Any help would be great.

```
plt.title("This is my title")
plt.gray()
shap.plots.bar(shap_values,show = False)
shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[-1])

plt.show()
```

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I suggest you inspect the source code and tinker it to your wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to swap the blue color with the red one in the shap waterfall plot.

My approach was modifying the file `_waterfall.py` in the shap lib, replacing the lines with `c = colors.red_rgb` with `c = colors.blue_rgb` and vice-versa.

Surely not an elegant solution but I just needed to generate 6 plots this way.